# Why can't Safari connect to "server.local", when Firefox and Chrome can? Is mDNS the reason?

Tags: network, safari, firefox, nas, bonjour

I have a new file server `freenas.local`. I can connect to it fine with Firefox and Chrome web browsers, but not with Safari browser. The server is announcing correctly on [mDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS), as measured by Firefox and Chrome success, and by `dns-sd` output. What is going on? How can I get Safari to connect?

Here are the specific results I get when connecting with the browsers:

- via regular http, to `http://freenas.local`

  - Safari: "**Safari can't open the page**. Safari can't open the page "freenas.local" because the server unexpectedly dropped the connection. This sometimes occurs when the server is busy. Wait for a few minutes, and then try again." (Trying again doesn't help.)
  - Firefox, Chrome: connect successfully, via http.
- via https, to `https://freenas.local`

  - Safari: "**Safari can't connect to the server**. Safari can't open the page "freenas.local" because Safari can't connect to the server "freenas.local"."
  - Firefox, Chrome: connect successfully, via https, with an expected warning about the website being unsafe, for known reasons related to the server's SSL certificate..
- via IP address, to `http://192.150.23.2`

  - Safari: connects successfully, via http.
  - Firefox, Chrome: connect successfully, via http.
- via IP address and https, to `https://192.150.23.2`

  - Safari: connects successfully, with an expected warning about the website being unsafe, for known reasons related to the server's SSL certificate.
  - Firefox, Chrome: connect successfully, via https, with an expected warning etc.

The behaviour I expect is that Safari connect in every case just as Chrome and Firefox do.

I used [`dns-sd`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/netbsd/1/dns-sd/) to test the mDNS (aka [Bonjour](https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/)) announcements. This is what I get:

```
% dns-sd -B _http local                        
Browsing for _http._tcp.local
DATE: ---Mon 13 Jul 2020---
18:39:32.525  ...STARTING...
Timestamp     A/R    Flags  if Domain               Service Type         Instance Name
18:39:32.526  Add        3   5 local.               _http._tcp.          freenas
18:39:32.527  Add        2   8 local.               _http._tcp.          freenas
18:39:32.629  Add        3   5 local.               _http._tcp.          Maker PR-1234 "printer"
18:39:32.629  Add        2   8 local.               _http._tcp.          Maker PR-1234 "printer"
18:39:32.692  Add        2   5 local.               _http._tcp.          OldNAS
18:39:32.929  Add        2   8 local.               _http._tcp.          OldNAS
^C
% dns-sd -L freenas _http local 
Lookup freenas._http._tcp.local
DATE: ---Mon 13 Jul 2020---
19:08:29.925  ...STARTING...
19:08:30.068  freenas._http._tcp.local. can be reached at freenas.local.:80 (interface 5)
19:08:30.105  freenas._http._tcp.local. can be reached at freenas.local.:80 (interface 8)
^C

# Updated 2020-07-17 in response to comments below
% dns-sd -G v4v6 freenas.local
DATE: ---Thu 16 Jul 2020---
20:07:23.448  ...STARTING...
Timestamp     A/R Flags if Hostname                               Address                                      TTL
20:07:23.647  Add     3  5 freenas.local.                      192.150.23.2                                120
20:07:23.647  Add     2  5 freenas.local.                      0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000%<0>  1   No Such Record
20:07:23.696  Add     2  8 freenas.local.                      192.150.23.2                                120
20:07:23.784  Add     2  8 freenas.local.                      0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000%<0>  1   No Such Record
^C

% printf 'GET / HTTP/1.0\n\n' | nc -6 freenas.local 80
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 17 Jul 2020 03:08:25 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 138
Connection: close
Location: http:///ui/
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1

<html>
<head><title>302 Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>302 Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

My Mac runs macOS 10.13.6 High Sierra. Server "freenas" runs [FreeNAS 11.3](https://www.freenas.org/), based on FreeBSD. I have changed the names of all servers and IP addresses to protect my network's privacy, but hopefully that doesn't obscure the important information. My workaround is to use Firefox instead of Safari, which is fine, but I'd like to understand.

Why can't Safari connect?  How can I get it to connect?

[**Edited** 2020-07-20, to add output from `dns-sd -G v4v6` and `nc -6` in response to comments below.]

Comment: You don’t connect *via* mDNS as its not a transport like http.  That said, don’t use `.local` TLD; there’s just too many issues.   Set your router so that the LAN domiain is .`.home` or something.  Just make sure it’s not already in use: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains

Comment: You are right, the wording "via mDNS" is clumsy. That's how Safari discovers the service, not how it connects.  You have a workaround to suggest, involving `.home`. Great! Make that an answer?  And please explain how web browsers would resolve the domain name `freenas.home` or whatever to the private IP address of the server.

Comment: I disagree about .local vs. .home -- .local is the proper TLD to use for mDNS discovery, while .home (or similar) would be appropriate if you were running a local unicast DNS service hosting the name. You're using mDNS, so stick with .local. As for the actual problem: is it possible it's a IPv4 vs IPv6 thing? Safari tends to prefer IPv6, and if there's a problem with that it might not switch to IPv4 (although for most types of problems it's supposed to).

Comment: @GordonDavisson thanks for the insight. How could I diagnose if it's an IPv4 vs IPv6 thing? FWIW nothing on my network is intentially IPv6. And `ping freenas.local` gives output with the IPv4 address, not IPv6. What extra information can I add to the question that lets you write an answer?

Comment: `ping` only does IPv4; you could use `ping6` to check IPv6 specifically, but try `dns-sd -G v4v6 freenas.local` to get *all* the addresses the server advertises over mDNS. It'll probably have an IPv6 address that starts with `fe80::` (indicating it's a link-local address) with a suffix like `%en0` (indicating which network interface it's reachable over). Getting a browser to *use* that IPv6 address is difficult, but you can do a real quick HTTP over IPv6 test with `printf 'GET / HTTP/1.0\n\n' | nc -6 freenas.local 80`

Comment: @GordonDavisson question edited add to output from dns-sd -G v4v6 and nc -6 in response to your comments. Thank you.

Comment: Back when I was administering Active Directory, we avoided .local as it caused many, many issues.  A quick search and it seems to still be a prevailing strategy: https://serverfault.com/a/811715.  Every network I’ve encountered with .local and networking issues was solved by renaming the TLD to something else.

Comment: @JimDeLaHunt It looks like the server isn't advertising an IPv6 address, so that's not the problem. Sorry; it's a red herring.

Comment: @Allan Active Directory uses unicast DNS, not mDNS (*multicast* DNS). The `.local` TLD is reserved for mDNS, so using it in Active Directory or any other unicast context will cause trouble. But for mDNS? It's the right thing; use it.

Comment: A lot of routers use Avahi for their mDNS and it has issues as well.  As a general rule, I've avoided it completely and my results speak for themselves.  What harm will it cause if the OP were to rename his domain in his router?  The worst that can happen is that I'm incorrect and it still doesn't work, so I don't understand the resistance.

Comment: @Allan my question is about Safari, not about which host name I should choose. The `.local` domain has specific semantics for mDNS, but Safari behaves differently than Firefox and Chrome when presented with the `.local` name.

Comment: I'm not referring to hostnames, I'm referring to top level domains.  I don't know why Safari acts the way it does when dealing with .local (I actually don't care), but I've solved the issue by avoiding it (in this context, .local; but I avoid Safari as well).  Nothing/nobody's forcing you to use this method; I just find the super high resistance to this simple solution quite interesting.

Comment: @Allan you are offering a solution to a problem, browser access to server, which I have already solved another way, by using Firefox. This question is about Safari's behaviour. I find the super high resistance to addressing the question quite interesting.

Comment: I'm only responding to the rebuttals so your "mirroring" reaction is quite telling.  Your description of your  solution is analogous to saying your found a solution to the problem with your Honda by using a Toyota.  I'm saying that the gas you put in your Honda is the issue - so even *this* response of yours interests me; you just so don't want to consider it that I'm actually more curious about the what's motivating it.  Maybe you think I'm an idiot, or maybe it's just pure obstinance -  I don't know, but it's a fantastic lesson for me when dealing customers with myopic tendencies.

Comment: @Allan My objection to to your recommendation that it doesn't just involve using a different TLD, it requires switching to a different name resolution protocol (unicast DNS instead of mDNS), with different network setup requirements, maybe different compatibility problems, etc. Depending on how the network's set up, it might just work, or it might be a huge can of worms. Also, it sounds like all (or at least most) of the problems you've had with .local come from trying to use it with unicast DNS, which will indeed cause trouble -- but isn't at all relevant here.

Comment: @JimDeLaHunt I've done a little more testing, and found that IPv6 might still be the problem. I found an old Mac that didn't use IPv6 and looked at how it showed up with `dns-sd -G v4v6`, and those "No Such Record" lines were not there. It's possible that the server is giving a garbled IPv6 advertisement rather than none at all, and that's confusing Safari (while the others recognize it's bogus and ignore it). I don't know FreeNAS, but is it possible to config IPv6 (preferably in local-only mode) on it and see if that fixes it?

Comment: Thats totally false, changing you TLD to something like .home or .office doesn’t require switching to unicast DNS! but hey...whatever.  Like I've said, I’ve solved lots of AD and SMB issues by steering clear if .local.  Though, I just love how you now looking at implementing IPv6 to solve a safari issue name resolution issue Chrome and FF don’t have.